# How to trim non-numeric characters with APEX transformation

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

During importing a CSV file I want to transform one column with money values so that it will insert them into database without problem.

I have values such as "134,245.99 RUB" and the output should be "134,245.99" or "134245.99" at best.

I tried doing it using transformation but there is no documentation (sic!) on that subject from Oracle how to use it.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tweant: You can use regexp_replace function and do this easily. Here's an example:

```
select trim(regexp_replace(' 2345abc ','\D*$','')) as str from dual;
```

This will remove all the non digit characters from the end and trim the white spaces.

More information about the function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).